# Upgrade Rails 2.3.14 to Rails 3.1.0, or re-write app fresh in Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have upgraded my app to Rails 3.1.0, and while I have solved many compatibility issues, but I have also noticed that there are many redundant files, junk codes, and some features I have to recode again.

I am just wondering if I should just rewrite my app from fresh in Rails 3.1.0, or continue modifying and fixing after the upgrade? The former one will produce a cleaner app, but more work, and the latter one will be faster, but will also take some time to clean up the mess. What is my best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

what I do is create a fresh empty rails 3.1 app.  Install my gems with bundler.  Then I copy over my migrations, my models and my spec tests.  Run my tests.  Get tests passing, resolve any incompatibility issues.  Repeat with config/routes, controllers, views, etc.

Comment: I don't have tests. That's why I now want to start writing test for each method...